# How to organize my CSS code for use into various bundles in Symfony2?

Tags: css, symfony

What I am doing right now is having one CSS file in the `\Web\Css\Style.css` path with all classes and ids of every element in my website. I have 6 bundles plus the base twig template's styles stored inside this CSS file. I begun to create headers for different sections e.g. "main styles" or "footer" but sooner or later it became a mess.

Right now I am just adding styles on the bottom of the file. How could I clean out and re-organize my CSS code? How can I use a separate CSS file for each bundle? Which is the most "professional" approach ?

(*) same happens for JavaScript files but there is a too small amount of code right now for it to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I find it better to maintain CSS and JavaScript files outside of any bundles. It's also easier to use tools such as Sass or Compass.

Ryan Weaver gave a talk on this topic on the SymfonyCon in Warsaw. You can watch it on YouTube:

- [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7iN5SFglMo)
- [Slides](http://www.slideshare.net/weaverryan/cool-like-frontend-developer-grunt-requirejs-bower-and-other-tools-29177248)
- [An example project](https://github.com/knpuniversity/symfonycon-frontend)